# What's the problem with log of sum, as opposed to sum of logs in probability theory?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, expected-value, bayesian

I'm reading about variational inference and expectation maximization, I often see this assertion without proof or explanation:

We have no problem with maximizing sum of logs as in

$\max_\theta \sum{\log{p(x_i, z_i)}}$

But we do have trouble with maximizing log of sum, as when $p(x_i,z_i)$ is marginalized to $p(x_i)$ using law of total probability, and as such you get a sum inside the log.
$\max_\theta \sum{\log{\sum_z{p(x_i, z)}}}$

Why is that?

Comment: You have two $\sum$ symbols in your final expression.  Was this intended?

Comment: @Henry The final expression extends from the previous one. I just used the law of total probability. They say we don't have trouble with outer sum and log being inside it, but we do have trouble with the log and the sum being inside it.

Answer (score 3):

A sum of logs is easily simplified as the log of the product, i.e.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log a_n = \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n a_n\right).$$

There is no such conversion for the log of a sum.

Comment: Dear, we don't like to optimize products. The total liklihood of data was originally a product of probabilities (thanks to independence) and that product got reduced to sum, cause we like to maximize log-likelihood instead. Am I right? it seems to me that you went one step back to where we started from.

Comment: What is the benefit of rewriting the sum of logs as the log of a product? I don't see that this makes the optimization problem easier to solve. Typically in maximum likelihood estimation one moves in the opposite direction.

Comment: @littleO Good question. The reason is because I don't have the z's, they are hidden variables, that's why I marginalized them out.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithms are strictly increasing functions and assuming that the logarithm is a real number, i.e. the sum is positive (or at least non-negative, as it should be if this is a sum of probabilities or densities or likelihoods or similar),

then the maximum of the logarithm of a sum is equal to the logarithm of the maximum of the sum and occurs for the same value of the variables

So $$\max_\theta {\log{\sum_z{p(x_i, z)}}} = \log \left(\max_\theta {{\sum_z{p(x_i, z)}}}\right)$$ is as easy to find as finding the maximum of $\sum\limits_z{p(x_i, z)}$

Comment: Actually, according to this:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174481/why-to-optimize-max-log-probability-instead-of-probability

It is better to have the logs